# Why do I need a server, username, and password to make a database in c#?

Tags: c#, database

I looked up how to make a database in c#, and all the examples I found explain making a database by connecting to a server. How do I make a server to connect to that is on my computer?

Comment: Well... why do you have to put in your username and password when you log into your computer or any site on the internet? Is this really a question, why do you have to authenticate yourself?

Comment: Visual Studio has a built-in web server that is used in development. SQL Server is similar; you have to connect to SQL `Server` to access it. You don't make databases in C#, you connect to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what brand of database you're working with, and what your application needs to do.

MySql, Oracle, Postgresql, and Sql Server (even Express Edition) are **database server engines**. They require having a server installed somewhere for a program to connect to. If all you want is a data store for a local desktop application, these are probably overkill for you, but they are well-suited for web sites or shared workgroup/enterprise applications.

Access and Sqlite are **in-process engines**. They do not require a server, username, or password. They make great data stores for desktop applications, but they're not quite as good as the prior options for workgroup or web site situations. Sql Server LocalDB can work well enough this way, too.

Each of these products uses the SQL language for querying the database, but they all have their own dialects... places where they extend or differ from the ansi-standard SQL definition.

Each of these also has different ways to install, configure, create accounts, and connect. Pick one, and we can help take you the rest of the way.